# How to get current query inside a transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I tried to get the current query from pg_stats_activity but that didn't work as expected.

Outside a transaction everything works:

```
pagetest=# select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 1 is not null;
                                       query                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 1 is not null;
(1 row)

pagetest=# select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 2 is not null;
                                       query                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 2 is not null;
(1 row)

pagetest=# select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 3 is not null;
                                       query                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 3 is not null;
(1 row)
```

But inside a transaction I get the wrong result:

```
pagetest=# begin;
BEGIN
pagetest=# select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 1 is not null;
                                       query                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 1 is not null;
(1 row)

pagetest=# select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 2 is not null;
                                       query                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 1 is not null;
(1 row)

pagetest=# select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 3 is not null;
                                       query                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid() and 1 is not null;
(1 row)

pagetest=# rollback
pagetest-# ;
ROLLBACK
```

It looks like there are some strange visibility rules on the stat collector views.  Is there any reasonable way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
  BEGIN;
    select 1,current_query();
    select 2,current_query();
   ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

by starting a transaction all future activity is invisible.
i use a second database connection to receive actual values.